# Restarting program while inside a program / text based game / C++

Tags: c++, recursion

My problem is that when you "die" in the game which is a simple text-based game you get asked if you want to restart or not if you say "yes" or "y" then the game restarts to the beginning. Thank you

I am terribly sorry if I did not copy the code correctly if copying the code from here does not work out then please write to me so I can arrange a google drive link so you can download the game.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//int rand_0toN1(int F);

int main() 
{
bool gameloop = true;

int F = 10, W = 10; //F = Food Level -- W = Water Level
int BegS, PG; //BegS = Begging Skills -- PG = People Giving choices
double thieveN, thieveI; //Thieve = Thievery -- thieveI = items you steal
int D = 0; // Number of days survived
int MC = 0; // Money checker, if you earn money then additional commands will be added so you can use money
int M = 0; // Amount of money
string c, sc, thieve; //C = Choice -- SC = Seacond Choice -- thieves = thievery strings

srand(time(NULL)); //set seed for random numberss
BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
thieveN = (rand() % 20) + 1;
thieveI = (rand() % 4) + 1;
PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;

cout << "Hello There, Lets get straight to the point. You are homeless in the streets of New York\n";
cout << "Yeah it sucks I know\n";
cout << "You will have to survive the streets\n";
cout << "If you ever need help with the commands of this game please type help\n";
cout << "\n";
cin >> c;

while (gameloop = true) {
    if (c == "help") {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Here are the basic commands of the Game\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "beg--To Beg what did you expect\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "levels--To Check your hunger and water levels (if any of your levels reaches 0 you DIE!!!)\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "steal--To Steal (will open a window for more commands)\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "die--this command will kill your character \n";
        cin >> c;
    }

    if (c == "die") {
        F = 1;
    }

    if (c == "levels") {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Your Water level is " << W << endl;
        cout << "Your Hunger level is " << F << endl;
        cout << "You Have currently survived for " << D << " days\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "levels" && MC == 1) {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Your Water level is " << W << endl;
        cout << "Your Hunger level is " << F << endl;
        cout << "You Have currently survived for " << D << " days\n";
        cout << "Your money totals up to " << M << endl;
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 18) {  //10% chance
        cout << "Your Beggging Payed of and A Kind Person Gave You Water and Food\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        D++;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 13 && BegS <= 17 && PG == 1) {  // 20% chance
        cout << "Your Beggging Payed of and A Kind Person Gave You Food\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        W--;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 13 && BegS <= 17 && PG == 2) {  // 20% chance
        cout << "Your Beggging Payed of and A Kind Person Gave You Water\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 14 && BegS <= 17) {  // 15% chance
        cout << "A Kind Person came by you and game you some money\n";
        cout << "(you can use money to buy either food or water by using the \"buy water/food\" command\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        W--;
        MC = 1;
        M++;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 3 && BegS <= 13) {  // 50% chance
        cout << "Sadly your begging did not get you anything\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        W--;
        cin >> c;
    }

    //-------------Specialty Items----------------
    if (c == "beg" && BegS == 2) {  // 5% chance
        cout << "You get noticed by some person who gives you a soda\n";
        cout << "(Items like Soda gives you +2 Water)\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        W += 2;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS == 1) {  // 5% chance
        cout << "You get noticed by some person who gives you a Pizza\n";
        cout << "(Items like Pizza gives you +2 Food)\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F += 2;
        W--;
        cin >> c;
    }
    //-----------------Thievery--------------------

    if (c == "steal") {
        cout << "What would you like to steal from? (gas station-1)\n";
        cin >> thieve;
        if (thieve == "1" && thieveN >= 12 && thieveN <= 16) { // 30% chance
            cout << "You have chosen the gas station\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "You manage to sneak a waterbottle into your pocket\n";
            thieveN = (rand() % 20) + 1;
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Would you Like to test your chances and steal something else?\n";
            cin >> thieve;
        }
        if (thieve == "1" && thieveN >= 17 && thieveN <= 20) {   // 30% chance
            cout << "You manage to sneak a sandwich into your pocket\n";
            thieveN = (rand() % 20) + 1;
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Would you Like to test your chances and steal something else?\n";
            cin >> thieve;
        }
        if (thieve == "1" && thieveN >= 1 && thieveN <= 11) {   // 40% chance
            cout << "You get noticed trying to sneak food into your pocket and get arrested\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "GAME OVER\n";
            cout << "You Survived " << D << " Days\n";
            Sleep(1250);
            cout << "Would you like to start over? (yes/ no)\n";
            cin >> sc;
            if (sc == "no" || "n") {
                cout << "Thankyou For Playing Hobo Life\n";
                gameloop = false;
                break;
            }
            if (sc == "yes" || "n") {
                cout << "You find yourself on a park bench, its early morning. Better start begging\n";
                cin >> c;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Invalid Input\n";
                cin >> sc;
            }
        }
    }
    //-------------Invalid Input-------------------
    if (c != "beg" && c != "levels" && c != "steal" && thieve != "1" && c != "die") {
        cout << "Invalid Input\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> c;
    }

    //-------------------Death---------------------
    if (F == 1 || W == 1) {
        cout << "You died\n";
        cout << "You Survived " << D << " Days\n";
        Sleep(1250);
        cout << "Would you like to start over? (yes/ no)\n";
        cin >> sc;
        if (sc == "no" || "n") {
            cout << "Thankyou For Playing Hobo Life\n";
            gameloop = false;
        }
        if (sc == "yes" || "y"){
            gameloop = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid Input\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cin >> sc;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, change `while (gameloop = true)` into `while (gameloop)`. Please, remember: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison for equality. However, it is not nessecary to compare a `bool` with `true`. The comparison results in `true` if the value is `true` and `false` if the value is `false`. So, this is a needless identity operation which can be left away.

Comment: I changed the `while (gameloop = true)` into `while (gameloop)` and I understand that the difference between `== ` and `=` but the program still shutdown like before. Sorry if I dont understand

Comment: I saw that you used it correct in other places. Hence, I wrote _remember_ instead of _notice_. ;-) Such typos can be annoying because the compiler is able to "understand" both but they have very different meaning...

Comment: The English "x is A or B" translated into logic is not `x == A || B`, but `x == A || x == B`.

Comment: @molbdnilo 's comment applies to `if (sc == "no" || "n") {` and the following...

Comment: thankyou for the comment @molbdnilo but the problem still remains

Comment: You can trim away all the details of the game from the question – the logic is important, but your 'dialogue' isn't. Read about the [mcve].

Comment: If you name your variables things like "food_level", "days", "choice", "money", and so on, your code will be easier to understand and you won't need to write so many explanatory comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restarting program while inside a program & text based game & C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660073/restarting-program-while-inside-a-program-text-based-game-c)

Answer (score 0):

Using break will force the inner most loop to exit.

```
 if (sc == "yes" || "y"){
        gameloop = true;
        break; // <--- exits your while loop
 }
```

Remove that and it should continue. If you want to truly restart, you will need to reset the game state, which you do here:

```
int F = 10, W = 10; //F = Food Level -- W = Water Level
int BegS, PG; //BegS = Begging Skills -- PG = People Giving choices
double thieveN, thieveI; //Thieve = Thievery -- thieveI = items you steal
int D = 0; // Number of days survived
int MC = 0; // Money checker, if you earn money then additional commands will be added so you can use money
int M = 0; // Amount of money
string c, sc, thieve; //C = Choice -- SC = Seacond Choice -- thieves = thievery strings
```

Comment: I added the reset state after `gameloop = true` this fixes the issue but to a point. When I try to input the game states me as dead and I am stuck in this loop. The only way to get out is to say "no" when I am asked if I want to restart

Comment: You need to reset the value of the variables in use. This isn't just a copy of the above code. I think you may just be re-declaring them. ei you need to change `int F = 10, W = 10;` to `F = 10; W =10;`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if (sc == "yes" || "y"){
    gameloop = true;
    break;
}
```

You break out of the loop – which is the opposite of what you intended – and you always do that because you also ignore the result of the previous conditional.

If you want to only accept valid inputs, you need to use a loop:

```
bool is_valid = true;
do {
    is_valid = false;
    cin >> sc;
    if (sc == "no" || sc == "n") {
        cout << "Thankyou For Playing Hobo Life\n";
        is_valid = true;
        gameloop = false;
    }
    /* The 'else' is important here. */
    else if (sc == "yes" || sc == "y"){
        is_valid = true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid Input\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> sc;
    }
} while (!is_valid);
```