# Restarting program while inside a program & text based game & C++

Tags: c++

I have been building this game for a while now and still can't fix this big problem. I am young and need guidance thankyou. My problem is that when you "die" in the game you get asked if you want to restart or not if you say "yes" or "y" then the game restarts as wanted but when I try to input anything else the program states we as dead and I am forced into a loop. The only way to end the loop is to type "no" when asked if I want to restart which closes the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//int rand_0toN1(int F);

int main()
{
bool gameloop = true;

int F = 10, W = 10; //F = Food Level -- W = Water Level
int BegS, PG; //BegS = Begging Skills -- PG = People Giving choices
double thieveN, thieveI; //Thieve = Thievery -- thieveI = items you steal
int D = 0; // Number of days survived
int MC = 0; // Money checker, if you earn money then additional commands will be added so you can use money
int M = 0; // Amount of money
string c, sc, thieve; //C = Choice -- SC = Seacond Choice -- thieves = thievery strings

srand(time(NULL)); //set seed for random numberss
BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
thieveN = (rand() % 20) + 1;
thieveI = (rand() % 4) + 1;
PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;

cout << "Hello There, Lets get straight to the point. You are homeless in the streets of New York\n";
cout << "Yeah it sucks I know\n";
cout << "You will have to survive the streets\n";
cout << "If you ever need help with the commands of this game please type help\n";
cout << "\n";
cin >> c;

while (gameloop) {
    if (c == "help") {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Here are the basic commands of the Game\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "beg--To Beg what did you expect\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "levels--To Check your hunger and water levels (if any of your levels reaches 0 you DIE!!!)\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "steal--To Steal (will open a window for more commands)\n";
        Sleep(50);
        cout << "die--this command will kill your character \n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> c;
    }

    if (c == "die") {
        F = 1;
    }

    if (c == "levels") {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Your Water level is " << W << endl;
        cout << "Your Hunger level is " << F << endl;
        cout << "You Have currently survived for " << D << " days\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "levels" && MC == 1) {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Your Water level is " << W << endl;
        cout << "Your Hunger level is " << F << endl;
        cout << "You Have currently survived for " << D << " days\n";
        cout << "Your money totals up to " << M << endl;
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 18) {  //10% chance
        cout << "Your Beggging Payed of and A Kind Person Gave You Water and Food\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        D++;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 13 && BegS <= 17 && PG == 1) {  // 20% chance
        cout << "Your Beggging Payed of and A Kind Person Gave You Food\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        W--;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 13 && BegS <= 17 && PG == 2) {  // 20% chance
        cout << "Your Beggging Payed of and A Kind Person Gave You Water\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 14 && BegS <= 17) {  // 15% chance
        cout << "A Kind Person came by you and game you some money\n";
        cout << "(you can use money to buy either food or water by using the \"buy water/food\" command\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        W--;
        MC = 1;
        M++;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS >= 3 && BegS <= 13) {  // 50% chance
        cout << "Sadly your begging did not get you anything\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        W--;
        cin >> c;
    }

    //-------------Specialty Items----------------
    if (c == "beg" && BegS == 2) {  // 5% chance
        cout << "You get noticed by some person who gives you a soda\n";
        cout << "(Items like Soda gives you +2 Water)\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F--;
        W += 2;
        cin >> c;
    }
    if (c == "beg" && BegS == 1) {  // 5% chance
        cout << "You get noticed by some person who gives you a Pizza\n";
        cout << "(Items like Pizza gives you +2 Food)\n";
        cout << "\n";
        BegS = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        PG = (rand() % 2) + 1;
        D++;
        F += 2;
        W--;
        cin >> c;
    }
    //-----------------Thievery--------------------

    if (c == "steal") {
        cout << "What would you like to steal from? (gas station-1)\n";
        cin >> thieve;
        if (thieve == "1" && thieveN >= 12 && thieveN <= 16) { // 30% chance
            cout << "You have chosen the gas station\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "You manage to sneak a waterbottle into your pocket\n";
            thieveN = (rand() % 20) + 1;
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Would you Like to test your chances and steal something else?\n";
            cin >> thieve;
        }
        if (thieve == "1" && thieveN >= 17 && thieveN <= 20) {   // 30% chance
            cout << "You manage to sneak a sandwich into your pocket\n";
            thieveN = (rand() % 20) + 1;
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Would you Like to test your chances and steal something else?\n";
            cin >> thieve;
        }
        if (thieve == "1" && thieveN >= 1 && thieveN <= 11) {   // 40% chance
            cout << "You get noticed trying to sneak food into your pocket and get arrested\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "GAME OVER\n";
            cout << "You Survived " << D << " Days\n";
            Sleep(1250);
            cout << "Would you like to start over? (yes/ no)\n";
            cin >> sc;
            if (sc == "no" || sc == "n") {
                cout << "Thankyou For Playing Hobo Life\n";
                gameloop = false;
                break;
            }
            if (sc == "yes" || sc == "n") {
                cout << "You find yourself on a park bench, its early morning. Better start begging\n";
                cin >> c;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Invalid Input\n";
                cin >> sc;
            }
        }
    }
    //-------------Invalid Input-------------------
    if (c != "beg" && c != "levels" && c != "steal" && thieve != "1" && c != "die" && c != "help") {
        cout << "Invalid Input\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> c;
    }

    //-------------------Death---------------------
    if (F == 1 || W == 1) {
        cout << "You died\n";
        cout << "You Survived " << D << " Days\n";
        Sleep(1250);
        cout << "Would you like to start over? (yes/ no)\n";
        cin >> sc;
        if (sc == "no" || sc == "n") {
            cout << "Thankyou For Playing Hobo Life\n";
            gameloop = false;
            break;
        }
        if (sc == "yes" || sc == "y"){
            gameloop = true;
            int F = 10, W = 10; //F = Food Level -- W = Water Level
            int BegS, PG; //BegS = Begging Skills -- PG = People Giving choices
            double thieveN, thieveI; //Thieve = Thievery -- thieveI = items you steal
            int D = 0; // Number of days survived
            int MC = 0; // Money checker, if you earn money then additional commands will be added so you can use money
            int M = 0; // Amount of money
            string c, sc, thieve; //C = Choice -- SC = Seacond Choice -- thieves = thievery strings
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Hello There, Lets get straight to the point. You are homeless in the streets of New York\n";
            cout << "Yeah it sucks I know\n";
            cout << "You will have to survive the streets\n";
            cout << "If you ever need help with the commands of this game please type help\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cin >> c;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid Input\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cin >> sc;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (sc == "yes" || sc == "y"){` shouldn't there be an `else` before that `if`? Since you check whether the input is a no, then whether it is a yes, and otherwise an invalid input.

Comment: And please convert your code into a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That serves two purposes: (1) It increases readability, hence makes it more likely you'll get an answer. (2) It's an excellent debugging technique: often enough, you'll solve the problem yourself while minimizing your problem code. Posting a MWE also proves that you've tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: You have redefined `F`, `W`, `c`, `sc`, etc. Please, debug your program to find the problems you have (a lot of problems). And think that if user type `die`, you cange `F` to 1, and when you ask to start again, if the user select anything invalid, you not change the `c` value, so in the next loop this variable has `die` again as value. If user type `yes`, you redefine `F` and `W` setting 10 as value, but out of this `if` block, you are using the other `F` and `W` variables with other values.

Comment: You should read a little about the cocnept of variable scope. Whenever you write `int var_name`, this variable only exists in this particular scope which is the area between two curly brackets (only exceptions being global and static variables but you have neither in your project). When accessing a variable that is defined in multiple places, only the innermost scope is used and other scopes are not affected! Good luck with future game development :)

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at some example code.

```
int main() {
    int F = 10;
    std::cout << F; // will print 10

    if (F == 10) {
        int F = 5; // This will declare a new variable F that shadows the previous F
        std::cout << F; // will print 5
    }
    // Leaving the scope of if, our second F goes out of scope and is destroyed
    // Our first F is still there though, and it's still 10

    std::cout << F; // Will print 10
}
```

You are doing the same thing in your code when someone enters "yes".

```
if (sc == "yes" || sc == "y"){
    gameloop = true;
    int F = 10, W = 10;
    ...
}
```

Instead of creating new variables, change the old ones.

```
if (sc == "yes" || sc == "y"){
    gameloop = true;
    F = 10;
    W = 10;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping we out, I will definitely keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring different variables with the same name in separate scopes.
(Giving two things the same name does not make them the same thing.)

Use two nested loops - one that plays a round of the game, and one that repeats those rounds until the player wants to quit.

Like this structure:

```
int main()
{
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        // Declare variables for a round here so you don't need to reset them.
        int food = 100;
        int water = 100;
        // ... more game state...
        // Now play a round.
        std::cout << "Let's play." << std::endl;
        bool still_alive = true;
        while (still_alive)
        {
            std::string command;
            std::cin >> command;
            // ... interpret commands ...

            if (food <= 0 || water <= 0)
            {
                still_alive = false;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Game Over" << std::endl;
        // Ask if the player wants to go again.
        std::string answer;
        // ...
        if (answer == "no")
        {
            quit = true;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```